# Kotlin .thenBy { it.toString() } not work?

Tags: sorting, kotlin

I try to sort this String: "2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123"

First, I sort by the sum of the numbers. If the sums are equal, I sort them as String. But for some reason sorting like strings(**.thenBy { it.toString() }**) does not work correctly. Help find out the reason.

```
fun orderWeight(s: String) = s.split(" ")
.map { it.toInt() }
.sortedWith(compareBy<Int> { it.toString().toCharArray().maxBy { it.toString().toInt() } }.thenBy { it.toString() })
.joinToString(" ")
```

expected:<11 11 2000 [10003 22] 123 1234000 4444444...> but was:<11 11 2000 [22 10003] 123 1234000 4444444...>

All description: https://www.codewars.com/kata/55c6126177c9441a570000cc/train/kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll kick yourself…

The text says:

> First, I sort by the sum of the numbers.

But the code says:

```
it.toString().toCharArray().maxBy { it.toString().toInt() } }
```

So it's not sorting by the *sum* of the digits, but by their *maximum*.  (The second string comparison is fine — but in the case at issue, it's not getting that far, because the max digit differs.)

If you replace `maxBy` with `sumOf`, you'll find it works as you require.

---

Also, as an observation, there's no need for the `thenBy`; `compareBy` can accept multiple comparators.  You need to add the parens, but then the compiler can infer the type, so it's marginally simpler overall:

```
.sortedWith(compareBy(
    { it.toString().toCharArray().sumOf{ it.toString().toInt() } },
    { it.toString() }))
```